# Properties of the interior of the domain of dependence $D(A)$

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, causality, topology

I have been reading the book *Semi-Riemannian Geometry With Applications to Relativity* by Barrett O'Neil, but I have some problems understanding the properties of $int(D(A))$, where $D(A)$ denotes the domain of dependence or Cauchy development of an achronal set $A$.

In the book *General Relativity* by Robert Wald, I found that $int(D(A))$ has the following property:

$int(D(A))=I^{-}[D^{+}(A)]\cap I^{+}[D^{-}(A)]$

which is, however, something that O'Neil doesn't mention.

I understand that property and I was able to prove it. However, O'Neil makes some claims that I don't know why are justified. Fo example, there is a lemma that says the following:

> *If A is achronal and $p\in int(D(A))$, then every inextendible causal curve through p meets both $I^{-}(A)$ and $I^{+}(A)$.*

The proof starts saying: We can suppose also that $p\in A\cup I^{+}(A)$.

My question is , why does O'Neil suposse that?. I understand that $int(D^{+}(A))\cup int(D^{-}(A))\subseteq int(D(A))$, but I cannot see why we can suppose that $p\in A\cup I^{+}(A)$. The identity $D^{+}(A)\subseteq A\cup I^{+}(A)$ doesn't help, I think.

In another part, O'Neil proves that if $A$ is an achronal set, and $p,q\in int(D(A))$ with $p\in J^{-}(q)$, then $J(p,q)\subseteq int(D(A))$, where $J(p,q):=J^{+}(p)\cap J^{-}(q)$. In the proof, he says that only two cases need to be considered: $a) p,q\in I^{+}(A)$ and $b) p\in J^{-}(A), q\in J^{+}(A)$. Again, I don't understand why.

Maybe there is a property of $int(D(A))$ that I'm missing, but I don't know which one.

What property or properties of $int(D(A))$ justify this kind of assumptions?. Is there an identity that help to characterize $int(D(A))$ in terms of $I^{+}(A)$ and $I^{-}(A)$?.

In another reference, I found the identity

$$int(D(A))=int(D^{+}(A))\cup int(D^{-}(A))\cup (A-H(A))$$

where $A$ is closed and achronal, and $H(A)$ is the Cauchy horizon of $A$. However, this identity doesn't help, and O'Neil makes the claims mentioned above before the section where he introduces the Cauchy horizons.